# Итоги 2017 года и поздравление с праздником

Tags: обсуждение, новости

Совсем скоро настанет новый год, и в этот предпраздничный день я хочу подвести некоторые итоги.

Год назад состоялись выборы временных модераторов. Так получилось, что моя кандидатура была принята, хотя, как мне кажется, это огорчило и, возможно, даже разозлило некоторых участников. Причина того, почему я решил оставить заявку, заключалась в том, что, по моим наблюдениям, наш сайт находился в увядающем состоянии: отсутствие хоть сколько-нибудь структурированной системы меток, отсутствие четкого свода правил и модерации сообщений, «заболоченность» дискуссий (во многих случаях завсегдатаи сайта ставили себя выше других участников, из-за чего развитие ресурса стояло под угрозой) и проч. Мне показалось, что в моих силах попытаться это изменить.

Нетрудно заметить, что наш сайт — в отличие от многих других — не обладает своим дизайном, на нем не проводятся регулярные «демократические» выборы модераторов, конкурсы и другие акции. Дело в том, что он «застрял» на бета-стадии, для выхода из которой требуется выполнить некоторые задачи. Одной из них была активность на Мете (где можно обсуждать любые вопросы, связанные с работой сайта — ошибки в переводе, новый функционал, предложения, модераторский произвол…), другой — 10 новых вопросов в день.

Должен с радостью сообщить, что за прошедший год мы вместе смогли выполнить эти задачи! Активность на Мете заметно возросла (хотя нужно бы ее подтянуть!), а показатель в 10 новых вопросов за день был преодолен к концу года (и теперь нам нужно некоторое время его удерживать). Я буду пытаться «достучаться» до администрации Stack Exchange, чтобы они рассмотрели возможность аттестовать сайт. Если это получится, то наступит новая стадия развития нашего сообщества.
Теперь мне хочется отметить отдельных участников, которые внесли большой вклад в развитие сайта в этом году:

- [М_Г](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/183327/%D0%9C-%D0%93), [Римма Михайлова](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/185295/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), [Shampar](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/4345/shampar), [Матвей Дёмин](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/3970/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%94%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD), [Артём Луговой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/3970/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%94%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD), [Galina Avanesova](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/177616/galina-avanesova) — спасибо вам за полезные правки сообщений, которые, безусловно, делают нашу библиотеку вопросов и ответов лучше;
- [Серж](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1826/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6), [М_Г](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/183327/%D0%9C-%D0%93), [Galina Avanesova](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/177616/galina-avanesova), [Arhad](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/186102/arhad) — без ваших голосов, которые стимулируют и приободряют других участников, наш сайт навряд ли бы существовал;
- [Людмила](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/247/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0), [М_Г](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/183327/%D0%9C-%D0%93), [Alex_ander](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/4309/alex-ander), [Римма Михайлова](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/185295/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), [Мимоходов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/179791/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2), [Galina Avanesova](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/177616/galina-avanesova), [Серж](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1826/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6), [slava1947](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/4707/slava1947), [Jasmin](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/187832/jasmin), [flossyU](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/183603/flossyu) — благодарю вас за интересные вопросы и содержательные ответы, а также за полезные и конструктивные комментарии. Стоит ли говорить, что именно на этом стоит наш сайт?

**Я призываю всех участников:**

1. голосовать — за или против — за сообщения. Это играет важнейшую роль в отсеивании плохих и выделении хороших ответов и вопросов;
2. задавать вопросы и давать ответы;
3. распространять информацию о нашем сайте, чтобы к нам могли присоединиться другие участники;
4. активно вносить предложения, ставить темы для обсуждения, сообщать об ошибках и недочетах. Это можно и нужно делать здесь, на Мета-сайте.

В заключение — вопрос: хотели бы вы, чтобы на сайте проводились различные тематические конкурсы (победители и активные участники которых, конечно, будут награждены)? Буду рад увидеть ваше мнение в ответах к этому посту.

С наступающим Новым годом!

Comment: Да... прочитал впервые это всё здесь... Все, кто участвовал тогда и сейчас, привет! Здорово, что благодаря вам, Aer, и еще нескольким людям наш сайт всё же функционирует, не надоедает (а если и надоедает, то ни к чему не обязывает).  Я здесь, можно сказать, каждый день бываю.

Answer (score 8):

Так получилось, что я латышка, гражданка Эстонии, родной язык — русский.
Так получилось, что я забрела на сайт совершенно случайно, в феврале прошлого года (болела, было время "где поползать").

Спасибо Людмиле, Артёму, Маркизу, М_Г — за поддержку и добрые слова.
Спасибо Морковкину-Мимоходову и Shampar`у — за "пинананье" и шпильки (чтоб не расслаблялась).
Спасибо Галине Аванесовой — за язык, почти забытый в "Постсовете".
Спасибо Aer и Community (вы же нас насквозь видите, в шапках мы или без).
Спасибо всем-всем за приобретённый опыт!

Так получилось, что с вами — такими разными — я встретила Новый год и очень рада этому.
На пороге Рождество. Пусть благолепие во всём пребудет со всеми вами.

С признательностью

Laura

Comment: Спасибо вам! Думаю, что Community так же приятно, как и мне, даже несмотря на то, что это бот :) С наступающим Рождеством!

Comment: Век живи – век учись! Зато теперь я знаю, что такое "бот".

Answer (score 6):

Я недавно нашла этот сайт и стала его пользователем. Мне здесь понравилось. Я благодарна за точные и развернутые ответы, за готовность прийти на помощь. Полагаю, что сайт полезен и перспективен, развивается в правильном направлении. Aer, ваша работа заметна. Тематическим конкурсам гип-гип-ура!)))

Хотелось бы, чтобы правила пользования сайтом были на родном языке и интуитивно понятны.

Всех с Новым годом! Развития и процветания!)))

P.S. Если кого-то ненароком задела, извините великодушно. Тон у меня по жизни такой - игриво-иронический. Борюсь, конечно, но порой он меня побеждает.(

Comment: Большое спасибо! Надеюсь, наше сотрудничество будет продолжаться! С Новым годом!

Answer (score 5):

Поддерживаю нашего модератора, думаю, он делает замечательно свою работу и, в частности, правильно сделал, что решил подвести итоги года. Спасибо за упоминание и моей скромной роли. Хотя, честно говоря, я пришел сюда, чтобы пополнить свои знания, ну а если удается поделиться тем, что приобрел, — еще лучше. И всем счастья в Новом году и удовольствия от общения на любимом нами русском языке!

Comment: Большое спасибо за отклик!

Answer (score 5):

Спасибо, друзья, Stack Exchange, спасибо!

За то, что вы есть - те, кому интересно

В глубь слова проникнуть, язык наш ведь гибок,

И мысль так свободна, а слову так  тесно.

Нам  сайт этот важен – он силы даёт.

Он нас развивает и к знанью ведёт.

Кто жизнь отдал слову, кто в самом начале  -

Здесь  истину  в спорах не раз постигали.

Пусть правит и дальше на сайте наука

И да не гнездится снобизм здесь и скука!

Давайте все вместе марку держать –

Культуру общенья всегда соблюдать.

Здоровья всем,  света, уйдут пусть сомненья,

Тепло войдёт и счастье в каждый дом!

Пусть радуют улыбки, поздравленья

С неповторимым светлым Рождеством!!!

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! С Рождеством вас!